# Five lectures in a day

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "a day" or "in a day" in my sentence?

> "I have five to six lectures a day."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to say. If you mean that you have six lectures every day, you can say without fear

> I have five to six lectures a day.

If, however, you mean that there is one day in which you managed to fit in six whole lectures, then you can say

> **Tomorrow/On Monday/On the 12th** I (will) have six lectures in a day.

I added the time markers to indicate that the emphasis is on a particular day. The phrase "***in a day***" expresses a certain surprise at the fact that you can fit so much (or so little) in that amount of time.

***In a day*** does not mean *every day*, but ***within a day's time***. Like in the saying:

> Rome wasn't built ***in a day***. ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rome-wasn-t-built-in-a-day))

Comment: Is that "in a day" necessary in the second example? I believe it is more likely that a person will say something like "Tomorrow I have six lectures throughout the day."

Comment: You do say it if you want to show that you fit _**that much**_ in only one day. It's an emphasis. Like this [newspaper title](https://www.radiotimes.com/tv/sport/andrew-flintoff-attempts-12-world-records-in-a-day-for-sport-relief/): "Andrew Flintoff attempts 12 world records in a day".

Comment: Agreed. But mentioning the phrase with a particular day like "tomorrow/Monday" sounds very foreign to me, might be because I have never used that ever. But mentioning the day that will be tomorrow, we will not really need the phrase anymore.